# How do i access a WebElement whose xpath changes using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

There is a website called Dokkan Wiki which has tons of cards from a mobile game and you can click one any one of them to see their details such as stats & artwork images. I want to find the `<a>` element that contains the link to each card's artwork image using `Selenium` &  `ChromeDriver` and i want to do this for each card on that website. However, after doing a lot of testing i noticed that some of the cards, have that `<a>` element in the following `xpath` -> `//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/center/span/div/span/a"` while some other cards, may have it on a different `xpath` like `//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/center/span/div/span/a"` etc. My question is, is there a way to find the `<a>` element for each card on the website using just one global `xpath` value or `cssSelector`? I don't quiet know how to handle this case where these paths and selectors change from card to card. Any suggestions?

Here's the relevant HTML code from the website using an example card linked below:

```html
<div class="lefttablecard" style="float:left;">
<table style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; margin-left:0; margin-top: 12px; padding: 1px;background: #FFFFFF;border: 2px solid #cc0000;border-radius: 7px;-moz-border-radius: 7px;-webkit-border-radius: 7px; box-shadow:0 0 4px #cc0000;" border="2px solid black">
<tbody><tr>
<td><center><span class="advanced-tooltip tooltips-init-complete"><div class="apng size250px" style="width :250px"><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dbz-dokkanbattle/images/a/a0/Card_1015570_artwork_apng.png/revision/latest?cb=20190612094333&amp;format=original" alt="Card_1015570_artwork_apng.png" style="max-width :250px"><span><a href="/wiki/File:Card_1015570_artwork_apng.png" class="image image-thumbnail link-internal">
```

P.S. Here's an example of a card object on that website : [card](https://dbz-dokkanbattle.fandom.com/wiki/Last-Ditch_Attack_Frieza_(Full_Power)) . The image i'm trying to get for each card is the one on the mid-left part of the website (big-animated rectangular one).

Comment: To make this question more useful to future readers, you should add the relevant HTML to the question. While the link is helpful now, it may go dead at some point in the future and then the question is practically useless without the added HTML as context.

Comment: @JeffC you are absolutely righjt, i didn't think about that. Should i post the HTML code as a whole or just the part that has to do with the question?

Comment: Please only post the part that is relevant to the question. What is relevant may change or new posters may not know what all is actually relevant. I would just make a best guess and post a smallish snippet of what you think is right. If it's not enough, we'll let you know and you can go back and get more. What we don't want to do is to post a massive amount of text into your question to the point that it's hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at a couple cards and it looks like this CSS selector will work for you.

```
div.lefttablecard table a
```

It will return a number of A tags but the first one is the one you want so you can use

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.lefttablecard table a"));
```

Generally the way I approach locators is to find the element that I want and then move up the DOM until I find something unique, e.g. an ID, a name, a unique class name, or some other unique attribute. I then start there and test the locators in the browser dev tools until I get a locator that works.

Comment: Awesome, i'll test it out in a bit. I was about to ask what your thought process was but you got me :). Very useful

Comment: It's definitely something you have to learn over time through trial and error. I try to start simple and then see what I get... if it's too many elements or not the right one, I add one additional filter and see what I get. I repeat that until I get down to the right one or a manageable number. With time you will be able to better guess what is more likely to work and you will get there faster.

Comment: This worked amazingly well. I think i understand how i should work on these things. I need to do the same thing for another element on there so that's going to be a great exercise. Thanks for the help and the kind words

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. If you get stuck on the other one, post a new question... but I would encourage you to work through it for a bit before posting. Part of learning is hard work... don't rob yourself of that.

Comment: Do you know how to use the dev tools in Chrome to test locators?

Comment: No idea, i haven't worked with Web Scraping for more than 7 hours total so i'm extremely new to all of this

Comment: I generally use the Chrome browser because I like the dev tools the best. When you get to your desired page, press F12 to open the dev tools. On the top of the panel should be the DOM, at the bottom should be the console. If it's not there press ESC to toggle it on/off. You can check CSS selectors using `$$()`, e.g. `$$("div.lefttablecard table a")` and it will return a collection that you can look through, click on an element, hovering an element in the DOM will highlight it on the page... very helpful in finding the right element. For XPaths, you can use `$x()` in the console.

Comment: Here's a console reference for Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities that explains what I just said in more detail and with a LOT of additional references.